# How mean and deviation come out with MNIST dataset?

Tags: neural-network, multilabel-classification, mnist

I am a novice at the data science, and I notice some repository state the `mean` value and `deviation` in MNIST dataset are `0.1307` and `0.3081`.

I cannot imagine how these two numbers come from. Based on my understanding, the MNIST dataset has 60,000 pics and each of them has (28 * 28 = 784) features. How do I convert this feature vectors to get the mean and deviation?

Especially, this should classify by the label, right? For example, the number 0 should have its `mean` and `deviation`. For number 1 should also have its `mean` and `deviation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `mean` : It is the mean of all pixel values in the dataset ( 60000 × 28 × 28 ). This mean is calculated over the whole dataset.
- `deviation` : It is the standard deviation of all pixel values. The dataset is treated as a population rather than a sample.

> What are the uses of these values?

Mean and standard deviation are commonly used to standardize the data in this case the images. Standardized data has mean close to 0 and standard deviation close to 1. You can read more [here](https://link.medium.com/jQqYtv6BtU).

> Why to standardize the data?

Standardization transforms your data in such a manner that it has unit variance.
According to Wikipedia,

> In statistics, the standard score is the signed number of standard
>   deviations by which the value of an observation or data point is above
>   the mean value of what is being observed or measured

Answer (score 1):

The repository is simply stating that amongst all features and all examples, the mean value is `0.1307` and the standard deviation is `0.3081`. You can get these values yourself, if you have the mnist training set loaded into a `numpy` array called `mnist`, by simply evaluating the methods `mnist.mean()` and `mnist.std()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps!

```
self.train_x_set = self.train_x_set / 255.
mean = 0
std = 0
for x in self.train_x_set:
    mean += np.mean(x[0, :, :])
mean /= len(self.train_x_set)
self.train_x_set -= mean
for x in self.train_x_set:
    std += np.mean(np.square(x[0, :, :]).flatten())
std = np.sqrt(std / len(self.train_x_set))
```